# Adding filebeat to ebextensions alongside a war file created with AWS Code Pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack

I have a Spring application that automatically builds and deploys using AWS Code Pipeline and Elastic Beanstalk.  In order to get that to work, I had to create an .ebextensions file fix-path.config as follows

```
container_commands:
  fix_path:
    command: "echo Hello world"
    command: "unzip MyApp.war 2>&1 > /var/log/my_last_deploy.log"
```

This was required because the output of CodeBuild was a war file, but was automatically zipped before deployment.  I have been setting up the ELK stack for logging, and wanted to use Filebeats to send logs from Tomcat to my Logstash server.  The recommended way to do this on Elastic Beanstalk was also an ebextensions config file.  I can't figure out how to get both the fix-path config and the Filebeats config file to live harmoniously though.  I have gotten Filebeats working with a config file like this (filebeat.config):

```
files:
  "/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      filebeat.prospectors:
        -
          input_type: log
          paths: ["/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log"]
          fields_under_root: true
          ignore_older: 3h
      output.logstash:
        hosts: ["url-to-logstash"]

commands:
  1_command:
    command: "curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-5.5.1-x86_64.rpm"
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
  2_command:
    command: "rpm -ivh --replacepkgs filebeat-5.5.1-x86_64.rpm"
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
  3_command:
    command: "/etc/init.d/filebeat start"
```

If I manually package the war file with this as in the .ebextensions folder, I can deploy it manually and verify that Filebeat gets set up properly.  However, if I use CodeBuild and include the fix-path.config file as well, the deployment hangs indefinitely.  I know the issue must have something to do with the order in which commands are run, and the fact that the unzip command needs to get run from the directory the artifacts are put in, but I can't seem to figure out how to make that work.  I've tried moving the filebeat stuff into the fix-path file, and adding the commands as container_comands, but that didn't work either. Has anyone successfully used CodeBuild + Elastic Beanstalk + Tomcat with multiple ebextensions?